# Trying to construct PostgreSQL Query to extract from JSON a text value in an object, in an array, in an object, in an array, in an object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am constructing an interface between a PostgreSQL system and a SQL Server system and am attempting to "flatten" the structure of the JSON data to facilitate this.  I'm very experienced in SQL Server but I'm new to both PostgreSQL and JSON.

The JSON contains essentially two types of structure: those of `type` "text" or "textarea" where the value I want is in an object named `value` (the first two cases below) and those of `type` "select" where the `value` object points to an `id` object in a lower-level `options` array (the third case below).

```
{
    "baseGroupId": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": "1f53",
                "name": "Location",
                "type": "text",
                "options": [],
                "value": "Over the rainbow"
            },
            {
                "id": "b547",
                "name": "Description",
                "type": "textarea",
                "options": [],
                "value": "A place of wonderful discovery"
            },
            {
                "id": "c12f",
                "name": "Assessment",
                "type": "select",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "e5fd",
                        "name": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "e970",
                        "name": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0ff4",
                        "name": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2db3",
                        "name": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "241f",
                        "name": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3f52",
                        "name": "5"
                    }
                ],
                "value": "241f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Those with a sharp eye will see that the value of the last `value` object "241f" can also be seen within the `options` array against one of the `id` objects.  When nested like this I need to extract the value of the corresponding `name`, in this case "4".

The JSON-formatted information is in table **customfield** field **textvalue**.  It's datatype is **text** but I'm coercing it to **json**.  I was originally getting array set errors when trying to apply the criteria in a WHERE clause and then I read about using a LATERAL subquery instead.  It now runs but returns all the options, not just the one matching the `value`.

I'm afraid I couldn't get an SQL Fiddle working to reproduce my results, but I would really appreciate an examination of my query to see if the problem can be spotted.

```
with cte_custombundledfields as
     (
            select
                   textvalue
                 , cfname
                 , json_array_elements(textvalue::json -> 'baseGroupId'->'fields') ->> 'name'  as name
                 , json_array_elements(textvalue::json -> 'baseGroupId'->'fields') ->> 'value' as value
                 , json_array_elements(textvalue::json -> 'baseGroupId'->'fields') ->> 'type'  as type
            from
                   customfield
     )
   , cte_custombundledfieldsoptions as
     (
            select *
                 , json_array_elements(json_array_elements(textvalue::json -> 'baseGroupId'->'fields') -> 'options') ->> 'name' as value2
            from
                   cte_custombundledfields                                                   x
                 , LATERAL json_array_elements(x.textvalue::json -> 'baseGroupId'->'fields') y
                 , LATERAL json_array_elements(y -> 'options')                               z
            where
                   type    = 'select'
                   and z ->> 'id' = x.value
     )
select *
from
       cte_custombundledfieldsoptions
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a much-simplified rewrite of this question which was answered by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi).

[How do I query a string from JSON based on another string within the JSON in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079358/how-do-i-query-a-string-from-json-based-on-another-string-within-the-json-in-pos/59079492#59079492)