# How do I query a string from JSON based on another string within the JSON in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

MyTable.MyField in my PostgreSQL database contains the following (simplified) JSON block:

```
{
    "base": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldid": "c12f",
                "fieldname": "sizes",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "choiceid": "2db3",
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "choiceid": "241f",
                        "size": "medium"
                    },
                    {
                        "choiceid": "3f52",
                        "size": "large"
                    }
                ],
                "answer": "241f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I use the value of `answer` to extract the chosen `size` from the `choices` array please (i.e. in this case "medium")?

(Note:  I have tried.  For a TLDR version of this question see [Trying to construct PostgreSQL Query to extract from JSON a text value in an object, in an array, in an object, in an array, in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071226/trying-to-construct-postgresql-query-to-extract-from-json-a-text-value-in-an-obj) .)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a lateral join, then just query the fields that you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  field -> 'fieldid' AS id,
  choice -> 'size' AS size
FROM
  my_table,
  json_array_elements(json_column -> 'base' -> 'fields') field,
  json_array_elements(field -> 'choices') choice
WHERE
  field ->> 'answer' = choice ->> 'choiceid'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I considered editing it because I think I picked up a few typos but as I'm a bit of a novice in PostgreSQL and JSON I thought it better to point them out and let you (or somebody else) edit if appropriate.  The first one is easy - a missing comma after the first SELECTed field; secondly you said to do a lateral join yet you didn't use the LATERAL keyword; thirdly I got an operator error on the final "=" character - is that because the final -> operators should be ->> operators?

Comment: @WayneIvory Thanks for the info! `LATERAL` is optional on set-returning functions iirc. And yes, `json` doesn't support equality, only `jsonb` does - casting to a string is easiest here indeed.